# How to modify domain mapping on grails before test executions

Tags: unit-testing, grails

Thanks in advance for your help!!

I have to change the sequence of Domain object, cause when is working according some environment variable, de PK will be assigned by sequence ( its value will be over 100M , and if it's working with another "scope", I will have to setup the PK of the same domain ( It`s about from a migrated process, so the PK inserted will be from 40M to 90M, it's on demand process):

As an example:

```
static mapping = {
  if (System.getenv("MIGRATOR")) {
            id generator: 'assigned'
        }else{
            id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'MY_SEQ']
        }
}
```

And I would like with my integration test do something like:

```
void "test  ..." {
System.metaclass.'static'.getenv = {return (it.equals(MIGRATOR))}
..stuff test about migration and thing related to insert add hoc Domain instance.
}
```

But I realize that environment is setting up before test running.. so I don't see another way..

Note: I do Integration test cause is an transactional code, with withTransactions functions, so as unit test, it doesn't work , I do it in this way, but, I hear another propose so I can change my point of view to test it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure that your mapping is correct with your env variables, you can do a integration test, and inspect your domain class mapping though the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.Mapping` instance:

```
Mapping mapping = new GrailsDomainBinder().getMapping(MyDomainClass)
println mapping.getIdentity() //id[generator:sequence, column:id, type:class java.lang.Long]
```

Another option is to set your variable in your cmd / console before running the test, take the advantage of running a single test in grails:

```
set MIGRATOR=true
grails test-app -integration package.TestSpec
```